# PnP powershell to enable documents to open in client app

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, document-library, modern-experience, pnp-powershell

I can enable this using the site settings, but I am looking to write a PowerShell script add into a PnP template to enable documents to be opened in the client application vs in the browser. This is for SharePoint online.

I cannot seem to find the feature ID when I look them up in PowerShell, does anyone know any documentation on how to find the feature id's for document libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Microsoft official documentation at:
[Set the default open behavior for browser-enabled documents (Office Web Apps when used with SharePoint 2013)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/webappsserver/set-the-default-open-behavior-for-browser-enabled-documents-office-web-apps-when-used-with-sharepoint-2013?redirectedfrom=MSDN),

Feature ID for **Open Documents in Client Applications by Default** feature is:
 `8A4B8DE2-6FD8-41e9-923C-C7C3C00F8295`

You can enable this feature using PnP PowerShell like:

```
Enable-PnPFeature -Identity 8A4B8DE2-6FD8-41e9-923C-C7C3C00F8295
```

[Documentation - Enable-PnPFeature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/enable-pnpfeature)

---

You can get the feature details using PowerShell commands like:

```
Get-SPFeature -Limit All | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like "*Open*" }
```

You can run the following command to get all features:

```
Get-SPFeature | select ID, DisplayName, Scope
```

[Documentation - Get-SPFeature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spfeature)

**References**:

1. [SharePoint 2010: List of Features](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7695.sharepoint-2010-list-of-features-id-displayname-and-scopes.aspx)
2. [SharePoint 2013: List of Features](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18729.sharepoint-2013-list-of-features-id-displayname-compatibilitylevel-and-scopes.aspx)

Comment: So the documentation for 2013 to SP online has not changed in this instance?

Comment: No, feature ID for this is same for SP 2010,2013, SP online, etc.